# Firestore transaction reading a doc that may have not been created yet

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Say that inside a transaction I will update some document, however, if the doc does not exist I will create one (ie, transaction.set()). Now my question is if the doc is not created yet, and some other process call creates it, can I be sure that the transaction will be called again so that I don't lose data?

In case the doc always exists, it is clear, if some other process makes a write on it, the transaction will be restarted, however, if the doc is not there, will the transaction watch for it so that if it is created while it is in the middle of the execution initiates restarts?

And here is how I'm doing doing the transaction:

```html
await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      docRef = db.collection("my_collection").doc("some_id");
      const doc = await transaction.get(sDocRef);

      let initial_data = {}
      if (sDoc.exists)
      {
        initial_update = initial_update({...doc.data()}) //actually only retrieve a subset of fields
      }

      //Some updates on other docs
         ....
         new_data = ....
      await transaction.set(docRef, {...intial_data, ...new_data}, merge=True);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document. 
> If you're not sure whether the document exists, pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents.

Additionally, if you're using transactions, please keep in mind of the following:

- Read operations must come before write operations.
- A function calling a transaction (transaction function) might run more than once if a concurrent edit affects a document that the transaction reads.
- Transaction functions should not directly modify application state.
- Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

Additional information could be found on this [link on updating data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) and [writing data for React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#writing-data).